# Anaconda Python installation error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

При установке Anaconda Python 2.7 на Win 10 64-bit столкнулся с проблемой. Ближе к концу установки выдает следующую ошибку

```
C:\Anaconda2\Scripts>conda update conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 167, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 633, in conda_exception_handler
    print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 543, in print_unexpected_error_message
    from conda.base.context import context
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 556, in <module>
    context = Context(SEARCH_PATH, APP_NAME, None)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 707, in __init__
    self._set_search_path(search_path)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 725, in _set_search_path
    self._set_raw_data(load_file_configs(search_path))
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 362, in load_file_configs
    expanded_paths = tuple(expand(path) for path in search_path)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 362, in <genexpr>
    expanded_paths = tuple(expand(path) for path in search_path)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\path.py", line 97, in expand
    return abspath(expanduser(expandvars(path)))
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 311, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Прошу помочь с этим (еще приложу скрин ошибки)
    [image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Исправил более менее, добавил текст ошибки, но скрин оставил, мало ли что. Прошу помочь.

Comment: По всей видимости у вас проблема с переменными Path, может нужно добавить что то в нее?

Comment: Похоже на баг при работе с Unicode в conda. Чтобы обойти, попробуйте из под пользователя с ascii именем запустить (чтобы в пути не было не-ascii (русских)  букв).

Comment: Переименовал пользователя, исключил utf-8 . Попробовал установить снова, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Можно попробовать поставить conda, которая реализована поверх Python 3, чтобы меньше проблем Unicode было. После успешной установки, можно создавать окружения и для Python 2 и 3.

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий ответ не помог (хотя я внес все правки). В файле `knownfolders.py` проверил, что в переменной path приходит unicode (вставил команду `print(type(path))`, поэтому просто закомментировал строки:

```
       #if hasattr(path, "decode"):
       #    path = path.decode(codec)
```

После этого запустил из консоли, запущенной из под администратора в папке `C:\Users\bulas\Anaconda2\Lib>` запустил команду `..\python _nsis.py mkmenus`. Скрипт отработал, ярлыки создались.

Answer (score 0):

проблему при установке проигнорировал, однако дальше не запускался jupiter notebook. Проблема в русском названии папок (`C:\Пользователи\Руслан\` в моем случае). Запустил путём правок в нескольких файлах:

- \Anaconda2\Lib\ntpath.py:

вместо `result_path = result_path + p_path`

```
try:
    result_path = result_path + p_path
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
```

- \Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py

вместо `homedir = os.path.realpath(homedir)`

`homedir = os.path.realpath(homedir).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`

и вместо `appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None)`

```
appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

- \Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py

вместо `home = os.path.expanduser('~')`

`home = os.path.expanduser('~').decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`